# How to change layout of product detail page?

Tags: magento2, layout, format

I've set up a child theme of Luma and want to change the layout of my individual product detail page. What file controls this? I don't see the .phtml file and don't see how changing block order in my xml will accomplish what I need to do.

Answer (score 3):

To change the layout of individual product detail page, as you have created the child theme assuming your child theme path is something like this

magento_root/app/design/frontend/company_name/theme_name/

Now navigate to your child theme and follow these steps.

> 1. Create a folder Magento_Catalog and inside it create another folder layout, so the path now looks like this
>      (magento_root/app/design/frontend/company_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/layout).
> 2. Copy your xml file from magento_root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
>
>    - Do not edit this as this is core file.
> 3. Paste the xml file under magento_root/app/design/frontend/company_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/layout/
>      now edit this as required.
> 4. Create the following path magento_root/app/design/frontend/company_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view
> 5. Go to magento_root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/
>      where all .phtml files are located which gets required data into
>      product details page.
> 6. Copy the required .phtml files from core folder(magento_root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/)
>      to your child theme
>      folder(magento_root/app/design/frontend/company_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view)
>      and edit them as required.

Hope this helps your question.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a single template file for the product page, you can manipulate it by layout.

See here the [doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html).

The main layout file is `magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

In order to see the templates that forms the parts of your page, you can activate the **template hints** in:

> Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Debug > Enabled
>   Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes

Comment: You should add that in order to properly change it, you will need to add the files to your custom theme keeping path directives properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change inside layout xml file,

if you want to display product details page 2column left then change file is **catalog_product_view.xml**

set layout value `layout="2columns-right"` inside `<page>` node.

```
< page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```